# Item won't update in database

Tags: python, database, django

I'm writing a method to update several fields in multiple instances in my database. For now, I'm trying to get it to work just for one.

My user uploads a CSV file with all the information to change (including the pk). I've written the function that parses all the information, and this all works fine. I can even assign the data to an item, and if I print it from that function, it comes out correctly. However, when I save the updates (using `item.save()`) nothing seems to change in the database.

Here's a very stripped down version of the method. I really don't know why it isn't working. I've done something very similar in other spots (getting data through a form, setting the field, calling save, and then displaying the changed information), and I've used a very similar CSV uploading technique to create new entries.

Small piece of relevant code:

```
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
  pk = row[0]
  print(pk)

  item = POObject.objects.get(pk=pk)

  p2 = item.purchase2

  print item.purchase.requested_start_date
  print p2.requested_start_date

  requested_start_date=row[6]

  requested_start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(requested_start_date, "%d %b %y")
  print requested_start_date

  p2.requested_start_date = requested_start_date
  p2.save()
  print p2.requested_start_date
  item.purchase2 = p2
  item.save()

  print item.purchase.requested_start_date

  return pk
```

Obviously I have lots of prints in there to find where stuff went wrong. Basically what I find is that if I look at `item`, it looks fine, but if I query the server again (after saving) i.e. dong `item2=POObject.objects.get(pk=pk)` it won't have had any updates. Does anyone have any idea why `save()` isn't doing anything?

UPDATE:
The mystery continues. 
If I update a field that isn't contained within an FK relation (say, a text field or something), everything seems to work fine. However, what I really need to do is update an item, and then set that item as the fk relation to the main item in question. I'm not sure why this isn't working in the normal way (updating the internal item, saving it, and then setting the fk to that new, updated item).

Comment: Are you overriding the save method for the POObject model?

Comment: This is probably just an artifact of pasting the code in here, but in the version above your `return pk` line is indented too far - it would happen at the end of the processing of the first line of your CSV.

Comment: @schillingt I'm not overriding the save method

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Yes, it was a mistake in copying the code over

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use a different variable name? `pk=pk` raises red flags to me.

Comment: @beroe: Why?  The first `pk` is a the keyword paramter, the second is the actual value.  It's a common idiom.

Comment: `pk=pk` is definitely not the problem. I use that all over the place.

Comment: What's the difference between `p2.save()` and `item.save()`?

Comment: `p2` is an instance of a model which `item` has an FK relationship with. I'm changing something in p2, saving it, and then setting `item.purchase2` to `p2` and saving that.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the models for POObject and whatever p2 is. Also, the lines `print item.purchase.requested_start_date` and `print p2.requested_start_date` seem to imply they are comparing the same value but one is `purchase` and the other is from `purchase2`...but I don't know the intent of those print statements for sure.

Comment: Isn't `p2` just a ForeignKey relationship rather than the actual object? What I mean is, should you get that using an `objects.get` query if you want to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoa. Feel a little ashamed that I didn't figure this out. I had forgotten exactly how I had designed one of my models, and there was another object within it that needed to be updated, but I wasn't saving it.